# Django / Visual Studio Class has no Object Error

Tags: python, django

I am receiving the following error in my Visual Studio code. There are no errors in my models.py file that this views.py file draws from, but when I debug in views.py in visual studio I get this error.

Based on other posts, I've pip installed pylint but that has not resolved the issue. Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

models.py

```
class Stakeholder(models.Model):
    employee = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    stakeholder_group = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    stakeholder_quadrant = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee
```

view.py

```
from .models import Question, Owner, Stakeholder

class StakeholdersView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/stakeholders.html'
    context_object_name = 'stakeholder_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Stakeholder.objects.order_by('id')
```

`Class 'Stakeholder' has no 'objects' member`

[image]

Comment: can you also post an example of your `Stakeholder` class code. To me, it looks like you have a custom object manager and it overwrites the default `objects` one.

Comment: Added the Stakeholder code from my models file

Answer (score 0):

check Stakeholder class in problem models file

Comment: No issues exist in the models file